# Два комплексных компонента на странице

Tags: битрикс

Есть страница `example.com/test`. На нее закинул два компонента: `bitrix:news` и `bitrix:photogaller`. Но проблема в том, что галерея отображается так-же и в содержимом новостях (в полной новости), т.е. на всех страницах вида:

```
example.com/test/?ELEMENT_ID=351845
example.com/test/?ELEMENT_ID=351846
```

А мне нужно, чтобы она отображалась только на странице `example.com/test`. Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Делай либо условие что то вроде: Если есть ELEMENT_ID в запросе, то нижний блок не отображаем.

Либо делай отдельную страницу для детального просмотра, лож туда комплексный компонент и с главной настрой подробный просмотр ссылкой на эту страницу.  Тогда уж лучше использовать не комплексный, а простой компонент.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна конечная задача. А так: Если инфоблоки Настройте разный шаблон URL для этих инфоблоков.